# Using OpenGL with Eigen for storing vertex data and glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: c++, opengl, eigen

I am trying to use `glVertexAttribPointer` with a structure of Eigen objects, similar to this:

```
struct Vertex {
    Eigen::Vector3f position;
    Eigen::Vector3f normal;
};
```

The problem is setting the offset of `glVertexAttribPointer`. Since there is no public access to the `m_data` member used to store internally the data in Eigen, `offset` cannot be used.

It seems like there is no nice way to do this. My current approach is something like:

```
(void*)((char*)vertices[0].Position.data() - (char*)(&vertices[0]))
```

, where `vertices` is a `std::vector<Vertex>`.

This is by no means nice (especially in modern C++). I doubt there can be a nice solution, but what would be a safer way of doing this, or at least how can this operation be isolated as much as possible, so I don't have to write it for every call to `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: Is that ever not zero? Why is there padding there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) guarantees that the layout of a `Eigen::Vector3f = Eigen::Matrix<float,3,1>` is as follows:

```
struct {
  float data[Rows*Cols];        // with (size_t(data)%A(Rows*Cols*sizeof(T)))==0
 };
```

In other words, the `float[3]` is at offset 0 of the `Eigen::Vector3f` structure. You are allowed to pass offsets of `position` and `normal` as-is (`offsetof(Vertex, position)` and `offsetof(Vertex, normal)`) to your glVertexAttrib calls for the offsets, and `sizeof(Eigen::Vector3f)` for the sizes.